# Button is not working when placed on background image

Tags: html, css

my button wont work when it is placed on this background image
this is the html and css i used

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 99.3vw;
  opacity: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100vw, 650px, 0px);
  height: 850px;
}

.learn {
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-top: 520px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#project {
  margin-top: 600px;
}
```

```html
<img class="bg-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487611459768-bd414656ea10?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTkwNjcyNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">

<form action="#project">
  <button type="submit" class="learn" formaction="#project">
    Learn more
  </button>
</form>

<h1 class="check" id="project">Check out my work</h1>
```

Button is showing on background image but is not clickable

Comment: the button is just covered by the picture because the picture is positioned absolute

Comment: This is because the image is absolutely positioned and has a higher stacking order than the button. Based on your current code, I would recommend you to learn flexbox and Grid before trying anything else.

Comment: or in general the box model and the meaning of display block to better understand the document flow

Answer (score 4):

Set the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to `none` on the bg img.

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 99.3vw;
  opacity: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100vw, 650px, 0px);
  height: 850px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 99.3vw;
  opacity: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100vw, 650px, 0px);
  height: 850px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.learn {
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-top: 520px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#project {
  margin-top: 600px;
}
```

```html
<img class="bg-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487611459768-bd414656ea10?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTkwNjcyNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">

<form action="#project">
  <button type="submit" class="learn" formaction="#project">
    Learn more
  </button>
</form>

<h1 class="check" id="project">Check out my work</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `z-index` and `position`

```css
.learn {
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-top: 520px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is img with absolute positioning is covering your button. Just add z-index: -1 to bg-img class.

```css
.bg-img {
  width: 99.3vw;
  opacity: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  clip: rect(0, 100vw, 650px, 0px);
  height: 850px;
}

.learn {
  margin-left: 550px;
  margin-top: 520px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#project {
  margin-top: 600px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487611459768-bd414656ea10?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTkwNjcyNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="" class="bg-img">

<form action="#project">
  <button type="submit" class="learn" formaction="#project">
    Learn more
  </button>
</form>

<h1 class="check" id="project">Check out my work</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your markup first. image should go under the button and also need to do some change in css. Try the code below, you will find answer:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
.learn {
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 520px;
    left: 520px;
}
.bg-img {
  width: 99.3vw;
  opacity: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 100vw, 650px, 0px);
  height: 850px;
}
#project {
  margin-top: 600px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<form action="#project">
  <button type="submit" class="learn" formaction="#project">
    Learn more
  </button>
</form>
<img class="bg-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487611459768-bd414656ea10?crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;fm=jpg&amp;ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MTkwNjcyNg&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;q=85" alt="">

<h1 class="check" id="project">Check out my work</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
</body>
```